# Unable to add files for review using P4 plugin for smartbear code collaborator

Tags: macos, perforce

I've recently set up my mac for code reviewing using p4v for file syncing/ changelists and ccollab for the review platform. Versions are:

MacOS - 10.15.7

Perforce - P4V/MACOSX1015X86_64/2020.1/1966006

ccollab client - 13_1_13100

Via the coollabgui app, I have the SCM verified and connected with no errors. I am unable to add pending changelists for review, but I can add submitted changelists. What's more is I'm able to submit files for review by manually uploading them through the web client. The big headache comes when I attempt to use the smartbear custom tool that installation builds into P4V. Attempting to right-click and add any changelist results in the following error:

No SCM Configuration could be determined

Cannot run program "p4" (in directory "/Applications/ccollab_client/ccollabgui.app"): error=2, No such file or director

I have reviewed the following other topics on the smartbear forums and found no solutions:
https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Collaborator/quot-No-SCM-could-be-determined-quot-p4-plugin-does-...

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Collaborator/Config-p4-plugin-on-Mac/m-p/44317

Any ideas? It's looking like this could be a potential bug.

latest log info is:

```
!SESSION 2020-11-30 09:13:08.279 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US

!ENTRY com.smartbear.collaborator.ui.standalone 4 0 2020-11-30 09:13:09.284
!MESSAGE Collaborator Enterprise version 13.1.13100

!ENTRY com.smartbear.collaborator 1 0 2020-11-30 09:13:11.024
!MESSAGE INFO: Mon Nov 30 09:13:11 EST 2020: com.smartbear.util.PoolThreadFactory
Thread CommandRunner-1325903125-1 created by thread ModalContext

!ENTRY com.smartbear.collaborator 1 0 2020-11-30 09:13:11.035
!MESSAGE INFO: Mon Nov 30 09:13:11 EST 2020: com.smartbear.util.PoolThreadFactory
Thread CommandRunner-1325903125-2 created by thread ModalContext

!ENTRY com.smartbear.collaborator 1 0 2020-11-30 09:13:11.060
!MESSAGE INFO: Mon Nov 30 09:13:11 EST 2020: com.smartbear.util.PoolThreadFactory
Thread CommandRunner-1325903125-3 created by thread ModalContext
!SESSION 2020-11-30 09:13:26.372 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US

!ENTRY com.smartbear.collaborator.ui.standalone 4 0 2020-11-30 09:13:27.238
!MESSAGE Collaborator Enterprise version 13.1.13100

!ENTRY com.smartbear.collaborator.ui 4 0 2020-11-30 09:13:28.388
!MESSAGE No SCM Configuration could be determined
!STACK 0
com.smartbear.scm.ScmConfigurationException: Cannot run program "p4" (in directory "/Applications/ccollab_client/ccollabgui.app"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at com.smartbear.scm.impl.newp4.P4System.getClientConfiguration(P4System.java:135)
    at com.smartbear.scm.impl.newp4.P4System.getClientConfiguration(P4System.java:85)
    at com.smartbear.scm.impl.perforce.PerforceSystem.getClientConfiguration(PerforceSystem.java:119)
    at com.smartbear.scm.ScmUtils.requireScm(ScmUtils.java:591)
    at com.smartbear.collaborator.ui.standalone.wizards.StandaloneScmConfigAddToReviewWizard$1.run(StandaloneScmConfigAddToReviewWizard.java:82)
    at com.smartbear.collaborator.ui.wizards.ProgressWizardDialog$AsyncWorkerThread.run(ProgressWizardDialog.java:231)
Caused by: com.smartbear.cmdline.ScmCommunicationException: Cannot run program "p4" (in directory "/Applications/ccollab_client/ccollabgui.app"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at com.smartbear.scm.cmd.impl.ScmCmdRunner.run(ScmCmdRunner.java:32)
    at com.smartbear.scm.impl.newp4.cli.P4CliConn.executeTextCmd(P4CliConn.java:147)
    at com.smartbear.scm.impl.newp4.cli.P4CliConn.<init>(P4CliConn.java:80)
    at com.smartbear.scm.impl.newp4.P4System.getClientConfiguration(P4System.java:120)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "p4" (in directory "/Applications/ccollab_client/ccollabgui.app"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at com.smartbear.scm.cmd.impl.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:70)
    at com.smartbear.scm.cmd.impl.AutoDebugCommandRunner.run(AutoDebugCommandRunner.java:48)
    at com.smartbear.scm.cmd.impl.ScmCmdRunner.run(ScmCmdRunner.java:27)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Just heard back from the smartbear community and got it fixed. In case someone else tries googling their way to success and needs the answer, it was this for me:

1. In the P4v client, select "Tools | Manage custom Tools | SmartBear - Add to Review" and click "Edit".
2. In the "Arguments" field, add the "--p4 your_current_path_to_p4" option after "--scm perforce".
   Note: Don't change any other options.
3. Click "OK", restart the P4v client, and try to reproduce the issue.